# html image slider not workin in php

Tags: php, slideshow

I recently changed all my html pages into .php pages for my new include header and footers and navigation. This is the first time I've ever ventured down php language and I'm having a hard time understanding how it affects the html code that I already had on my previous pages.

One problem I am having was my simple slideshow of pictures that is now no longer sliding. It is just stopped on the first picture, instead of rotating through 4 pictures.

Do I have to add new php language to make it work again? Does anyone know what php coding below is stopping it from working?

**Php header code below:**

```
 <?php
require_once("calendar/includes/config.php");

$db_connection = mysql_connect ($DBHost, $DBUser, $DBPass) OR die (mysql_error());  
$db_select = mysql_select_db ($DBName) or die (mysql_error());
$db_table = $TBL_PR . "events";

$query = "SELECT * FROM calendar_category WHERE status=1";

$query_result = mysql_query($query);

while($query_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query_result)){
    if(empty($andcat)) $andcat = " (`category` = $query_fetch[0] OR `category` LIKE '$query_fetch[0],%' OR `category` LIKE '%,$query_fetch[0],%' OR `category` LIKE '%,$query_fetch[0]')";
    else $andcat .= " OR (`category` = $query_fetch[0] OR `category` LIKE '$query_fetch[0],%' OR `category` LIKE '%,$query_fetch[0],%' OR `category` LIKE '%,$query_fetch[0]')";
}


$query2 = "SELECT * FROM $db_table where STR_TO_DATE(concat(event_day,',',event_month,',',event_year),'%d,%m,%Y') >= curdate() AND (".$andcat." )
order by STR_TO_DATE(concat(event_day,',',event_month,',',event_year),'%d,%m,%Y') LIMIT 3";

$query_result2 = mysql_query($query2);


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Creative Minds International PCS</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="description" content="Your description">

    <meta name="keywords" content="Your keywords">

    <meta name="author" content="Your name">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Vollkorn' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script src="site/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

    <script src="site/js/script.js"></script>

    <script src="site/js/flashobject.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 7]>

        <div class='aligncenter'><a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg"border="0"></a></div>  

    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>

        <script src="js/html5.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css"> 

    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">

<!--

var image1=new Image()

image1.src="../slideshow3.jpg" 

var image2=new Image()

image2.src="../slideshow2.jpg"

var image3=new Image()

image3.src="../slideshow4.jpg"

var image4=new Image()

image4.src="../slideshow1.jpg"

//-->

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-28106351-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
    </head>


<body id="page2">



<div class="main-bg">

<header><?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>   

    <div class="nav-container" >
<navigation><?php include('includes/nav.php'); ?>      



            <div class="clear"></div>

            </div>


                 <div class="flash" >

                    <div id="head">

                    <div class="aligncenter"><img src="slideshow3.jpg"  alt="Creative Minds Slideshow" width="990" height="450" id="Slideshow">   <script>

        <!--

        //variable that will increment through the images

        var step=1

        function slideit(){

        //if browser does not support the image object, exit.

        if (!document.images)

        return

        document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")

        if (step<4)

        step++

        else

        step=1

        //call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds

        setTimeout("slideit()",6000)

        }

        slideit()

        //-->

        </script>             

        </div></div>

    </div>  

</header>
```

Comment: The only php is at the first few paragraphs. 

Do I need to make my non-functioning slideshow work through php?

Answer (score 0):

Do two things:

1. Check your Apache error log for hidden errors
2. remove white spaces before the doctype:
   change

   ?>

   < !DOCTYPE html>

to

```
?><!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I guess I'm such a newbie, I have NO IDEA what an apache log is. I"ll have to google it. Should I have it on my computer or is it an online validation service for php?

Comment: It is on your computer. It is the web server (a software) that serves your PHP files to the browser. Look, if u want to develop web, YOU MUST understand first the architecture behind it, as it affects some aspects (like stateless vs state)